# iOS Framework and Crash reporting

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

I'm developing an iOS framework and I like to be able to log data for posible crashes. I don't like to use external logging framework like Fabric to avoid conflicts with the main app that uses the framework. Which should be the best approach to do that. Can I use the dsym files in any way? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand what you're trying to achieve; you'd like to get crash reports from apps which link against your framework however only if they occurred directly as a result of the code provided by the framework?

This would be fairly difficult to achieve, as crashes occur at the process level rather than your framework having its own isolated 'section' or subprocess.

You could potentially catch some Objective-C exceptions by writing code to detect and prevent them from resulting in crashes, however major faults such as `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` would not be 'detectable' without processing the app's crash logs.

If you decide to analyse the crash logs themselves (e.g. when the app next launches), this would require the dSYM of the specific *application* and build to symbolicate the crash. Once you've symbolicated the crash, you'd then need some logic to determine if the crash was likely due to your framework or not. If you receive crash reports from multiple apps, you'd need to ensure that you use the correct dSYM for each log, as this will very likely be different for each one.